# Set scatter chart in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

i would like to implement simple VBA code which draws scatter chart between  two variable, let us suppose that our data is given in range of  A2:B51, with help of stackoverflow, i found code which draws scatter chart  and it is  given here  :

scatter chart

[image: 1]

i am interested if  we can change code a bit so that  x values limit can be automatically corrected  in range of (xmin,xmax)  and  also between them add trendline?

code is given here

```vb
Private Sub scatter_chart_Click()
Dim xrng As Range
Dim yrng As Range


Set xrng = Range("A2:A51")
Set yrng = Range("B2:B51")

Dim Chart1 As Chart
    Set Chart1 = Charts.Add

 With Chart1
        .ChartType = xlXYScatter
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        'Change to what your series should be called
        .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""Price Versus Demand"""
        .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = xrng
        .SeriesCollection(1).Values = yrng
End With


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub scatter_chart_Click()
    Dim xrng As Range
    Dim yrng As Range
    Set xrng = Range("A2:A51")
    Set yrng = Range("B2:B51")
    Dim Chart1 As Chart
    Set Chart1 = Charts.Add
    With Chart1
        .ChartType = xlXYScatter
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        'Change to what your series should be called
        .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""Price Versus Demand"""
        .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = xrng
        .SeriesCollection(1).Values = yrng
        .Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = Application.Min(xrng)
        .Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = Application.Max(xrng)
        .FullSeriesCollection(1).Trendlines.Add Type:=xlLinear, _
        Forward:=0, Backward:=0, DisplayEquation:=0, DisplayRSquared:=0, _
        Name:="Linear (Price Versus Demand)"
    End With
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Axis.MinimumScale property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.axis.minimumscale?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm561090)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Trendlines object (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.trendlines(object)?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm591072)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

[image]

Comment: i can't upvote, please if you  give me a upvote i will also upvote it

Comment: You can try now.

Comment: yes i have done. thanks a lot